# Select shift based on current time between start and end time

Tags: sql, sql-server, date, datetime

I want to Select shift using **Current Time** Between **StartTime** to **EndTime**

```
ShiftID     OrgID   ShiftName   StartTime                   EndTime
13          1-1     General     1900-01-01 09:00:00.000     1900-01-01 17:00:00.000
14          1-2     Morning     1900-01-01 08:00:00.000     1900-01-01 15:00:00.000
15          1-3     Evening     1900-01-01 15:00:00.000     1900-01-01 21:00:00.000
16          1-4     Night       1900-01-01 21:00:00.000     1900-01-01 08:00:00.000
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From your question, you can try to use `CAST(CAST(GETDATE() AS TIME) AS DATETIME)` to set the date as `1900-01-01` time we only compare the `time` value.

check `Night` need to use a little skill, because the value will cross date.

when the `GETDATE()` time between `'00:00:00'` and `'08:00:00'` mean cross date.
so we need to add one date for `CAST(CAST(GETDATE() AS TIME) AS DATETIME)`

```
CREATE TABLE T(
   ShiftID INT,
   OrgID VARCHAR(50),
   ShiftName VARCHAR(50),
   StartTime DATETIME,
   EndTime DATETIME
);


INSERT INTO T VALUES (13,'1-1','General','1900-01-01 09:00:00.000','1900-01-01 17:00:00.000');
INSERT INTO T VALUES (14,'1-2','Morning','1900-01-01 08:00:00.000','1900-01-01 15:00:00.000');
INSERT INTO T VALUES (15,'1-3','Evening','1900-01-01 15:00:00.000','1900-01-01 21:00:00.000');
INSERT INTO T VALUES (16,'1-4','Night','1900-01-01 21:00:00.000','1900-01-01 08:00:00.000');
```

**Query 1**:

```
SELECT t1.*
FROM T t1
WHERE   
   CASE WHEN CONVERT(datetime,CONVERT(varchar(8),GETDATE(),108))  BETWEEN CONVERT(DATETIME,'00:00:00') AND CONVERT(DATETIME,'00:08:00') 
             THEN CONVERT(datetime,CONVERT(varchar(8),GETDATE(),108))  + 1
             ELSE CONVERT(datetime,CONVERT(varchar(8),GETDATE(),108)) 
   END
         BETWEEN StartTime 
   AND 
         CASE WHEN ShiftName = 'Night' 
            THEN EndTime + 1 
            ELSE EndTime
         END
```

**[Results](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/fe1c04/70/0)**:

```
| ShiftID | OrgID | ShiftName |            StartTime |              EndTime |
|---------|-------|-----------|----------------------|----------------------|
|      13 |   1-1 |   General | 1900-01-01T09:00:00Z | 1900-01-01T17:00:00Z |
|      14 |   1-2 |   Morning | 1900-01-01T08:00:00Z | 1900-01-01T15:00:00Z |
```

Comment: This is far more complicated than you think it is. Notice that (i) OP has 1900-01-01 in dates and (ii) notice the last record... night shift starts before midnight and ends after midnight.

Comment: when i use you **Query 1:**  then i have face some Error
`SELECT t1.* FROM T t1
CROSS APPLY (
   SELECT 
         CAST(CAST(GETDATE() AS TIME) AS DATETIME) nowDt,
         CASE WHEN ShiftName = 'Night' 
            THEN EndTime + 1 
            ELSE EndTime
         END EndTime
) v
WHERE 
   nowDt BETWEEN StartTime AND v.EndTime`

Comment: @D-Shih Error is 
`Msg 170, Level 15, State 1, Line 2
Line 2: Incorrect syntax near 'APPLY'.
Msg 170, Level 15, State 1, Line 12
Line 12: Incorrect syntax near 'v'.`

Comment: What's your sql server version?

Comment: SQL 2005 Express

Comment: @WaqarYousufZai your sql server version didn't support `CROSS APPLY` so you can try my edit answer. move `CASE WHEN` condition in the where clause.

Comment: @D-Shih  apply Query `SELECT t1.*
FROM T t1
WHERE 
   CASE WHEN CAST(GETDATE() AS TIME) BETWEEN CAST('00:00:00' AS TIME) AND  CAST('07:59:59' AS TIME)
             THEN CAST(CAST(GETDATE() AS TIME) AS DATETIME) + 1
             ELSE CAST(CAST(GETDATE() AS TIME) AS DATETIME) 
   END BETWEEN 
       StartTime 
   AND 
         CASE WHEN ShiftName = 'Night' 
            THEN EndTime + 1 
            ELSE EndTime
         END` and then error is 
`Msg 243, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
Type TIME is not a defined system type.`

Comment: @WaqarYousufZai I edit it you can try it, sql server 2005 didn't support time type.

Comment: @D-Shih Thanks Bro.

Answer (score 2):

A simple `BETWEEN` clause is not enough to handle the midnight case. You could do something like this:

```
SELECT *
FROM shifts
CROSS APPLY (
    SELECT CONVERT(DATETIME, CONVERT(VARCHAR(8), GETDATE(), 108)) AS CurrTime
) AS ca
WHERE
    (EndTime > StartTime AND CurrTime >= StartTime AND CurrTime < EndTime) OR
    (EndTime < StartTime AND (CurrTime < EndTime OR CurrTime >= StartTime));
```

[Updated SQL Fiddle](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!18/c6a12/8)

Comment: See revised answer. If `CROSS APPLY` is not available, simply declare a variable and use it in your query `DECLARE @CurrTime AS DATETIME = CONVERT(VARCHAR(8), GETDATE(), 108)`.

Answer (score 1):

assuming that the StartTime and EndTime are in datetime data type

```
declare @now datetime

-- this will convert current date time to 1900-01-01 + time
select @now = convert(datetime, convert(time, getdate()))

select  *
from    @shift s
where   @now >= StartTime
and     @now <  case when StartTime < EndTime 
                     then EndTime 
                     else dateadd(day, 1, EndTime) 
                     end
```

Comment: Tiny correction: `@now <=` should be `@now <`. Otherwise at exactly `15:00` it will match the shift that ends at `15:00` and the one that starts at `15:00`.